# Can I use reviews hosted on my own domain for AdWords review extension?

Tags: microdata, google-ads, website-review

I am gathering reviews for my eshop by a third party service but the service is not using 
schema.org to mark up the reviews.

This means that I can't use them for [AdWords review extensions](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/3236114?hl=en).

I have exported the reviews to my own domain (and added schema.org markup for aggregate reviews).

Will AdWords use reviews from my own domain when displaying my ads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's [review extensions policies](https://support.google.com/adwordspolicy/answer/3197294) indicates that the reviews must  be hosted in their original location:

> The following types of reviews are prohibited:
>
> - Second-hand reporting (rather than directly linking to source)

Using reviews that have been copied to your own site would not be allowed under this policy.

Comment: Thanks. Too bad the Google trusted store certification is only available in the US.